# Using Hashes in URL to Run Script onload

Tags: javascript, hash

I was wanting to make a link similar to this

www.mysite.com/profile/#openTheme

When the link has the hash "#openTheme" i want it to run a function on the page when the page is loaded.

Is there a way to set an Anchor like this eg:

```
<a name="openTheme" onActivate="runScript()">
```

Or is there a better way of doing it? Eg, running a script onload to find any location hashes and using if/else?

Thanks.

Comment: It wouldn't be that simple, are you willing to use a framework like jQuery or should I hack something together in regular JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pick this up using this:

```
self.document.location.hash
```

This will return #openTheme in this case.  You can then do an if, so...

```
if(self.document.location.hash == '#openTheme')
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Worked a treat! Thanks chief.

Answer (score 0):

You can register the `window.onhashchange` event, which will fire whenever the user types a new hash into the address bar, or a link is clicked that points to a hash on the current page, or JavaScript sets location.href to "#something-or-other".